# Element in the array such that the sum of the elements on its left is equal to the sum of the elements on its right

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, time-complexity

I am trying to solve Sherlock and Array algorithm task. I have array and i need to find element in the array such that the sum of the elements on its left side is equal to the elements of it's right side, like i mentioned in the title. My algorithm works for small arrays, but for big arrays it is too slove, what can i do to improve it's speed ?

Just to mention. This algorithm dont accept arrays of size 1 and 2.

```
public static boolean isSherlock(int arr[])
{
    int length = arr.length;
    int leftSum = 0;
    int rightSum = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<length-1; i++)
    {
        leftSum = 0;
        rightSum = 0;

        // Left sum for index i
        for(int j=0; j<i; j++)
            leftSum+=arr[j];

        // Right sum for index i
        for(int j=i+1; j<length && leftSum != 0; j++)
            rightSum+=arr[j];

        if(leftSum == rightSum && leftSum != 0 && rightSum != 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This is O(N^2) is there any way to do it in O(n) ?

Comment: If you have any element in the array and you know the left sum and the right sum. How can you update these sums when you go one element further? How can you initialize these sums at the beginning?

Comment: @NicoSchertler I don't think i understood your question. But every time when we move to the next index for which we want to check it's left and right sum, then we must set sums again to  0, right ?

Comment: No, that's my point. You just need to add the current element to the left sum and subtract the next element from the right sum.

Comment: @NicoSchertler You're right. Let me try again, and if it doesn't work i will update my new code. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At, first store the sum and then use that sum. Here is the code below:

```
 public static boolean isSherlock(int arr[])
    {

        int length = arr.length;
        int sum = 0;

        for(int i=0; i<length; ++i)
            sum += arr[i];

        int rightSum = sum-arr[0];
        int leftSum = 0;

        for(int i=0; i<length-1; ++i){

            if(leftSum == rightSum)
                return true;

            leftSum += arr[i];
            rightSum -= arr[i+1];
        }

    if (leftSum == rightSum)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: It works perfect. But we can also check in for loop if leftSum > rightSum and if it is true we can exit loop. Am i right ?

Comment: Yup, It should be work. It will reduce the number of loops.

Comment: What about first and last element of array? are {10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0} and {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20} sharlock in position respectively 0 and 8?

Comment: @user6904265 I don't think your arrays got Sherlock position ? There is no sum on left and right that can be equal in any index value, right ?

Comment: If you consider left sum 0 in position 0 then {10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0} is sherlock in position 0.

Answer (score 3):

The linear solution is pretty easy.

Calculate the sum of all elements in the array *A*. Of course, it can be done in linear time. Call it *S*.

Then iterate over all elements and store two sums: the sum of all elements which lie to the left on the current element and the sum of all elements which lie to the right on the current elements. Call them *L* and *R*.

For the first element *A[0]*:

```
L = 0
R = S - A[0]
```

When you move to *A[i]* you recalculate *L* and *R*:

```
L = L + A[i - 1]
R = R - A[i]
```

If *L == R* then the current elements is the answer.

Comment: It works perfect ! This is explanation i needed, thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You could save the left sum and rigth sum computed at previous step as follows:

```
int sumLeftStepI=0;
int sumRigthStepI = Arrays.stream(a).sum() - a[0];
for (int i=0; i<a.length;i++){
    if(sumLeftStepI==sumRigthStepI){
        System.out.println("found element at position a["+i+"]");
    }
    if(i<a.length-1){
      sumLeftStepI+=a[i];
      sumRigthStepI-=a[i+1];
    }
}
```

In this way the complexity should be O(n).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public static boolean isSherlock(int arr[]) 
{
    if (arr.length > 2) {
        int i = 1;
        for (; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
            int k = 0;
            int rhs = arr[i + 1];
            int lhs = arr[i - 1];

            int j = arr.length - 1;

            // **In single iteration it is suming from left as well as from right**
            while (k < i - 1 && j > i + 1) {
                rhs += arr[j--];
                lhs += arr[k++];
            }
            // **************

            // If any elements remain
            while (k < i - 1)
                lhs += arr[k++];

            while (j > i + 1)
                rhs += arr[j--];

            // compare
            if (rhs == lhs && lhs != 0 && rhs != 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**No need to create a separate variable for sum**. Assign the sum value to the right or the left.
This is the **most efficient** code that I came up with.

> Also it is obvious that for array of length less than 3, result would
>   always be false.

```
private static boolean balanceIntArrray(int[] nums) {
    int length = nums.length;
    if (length < 3) {
        return false;
    }

    int left = nums[0];
    int right = 0;

    for (int i = 2; i < nums.length; i++) {
        right += nums[i];
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < nums.length - 1; i++) {
        if (left == right) {
            return true;
        }
        left += nums[i];
        right -= nums[i + 1];
    }

    return (left == right);
}
```